# PHP: Can't remove node from DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I Can't remove node from DOMDocument(get Exception):

**My Code:**

```
<?php
    function filterElements($htmlString) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
          $node=$nodes->item($i)
          if ($value->nodeValue == 'my_link') {
           $doc->removeChild($node);
          }
        }
    }
    $htmlString = '<div>begin..</div>this tool<a name="my_link">Beo</a> great!<div>.end</div>';
    filterKeyLinksElements($htmlString);
    ?>
```

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: `My Code` - I doubt that. Parse error because of missing semicolon, different function names, $value instead of $node  ...this code was never executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete element with DOMDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, what exception are you getting (It likely matters).

As for the specific problem, my guess would be as follows::

The `$node` is not a child of the document.  It's a child of its parent.  So you'd need to do:

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```